# Pass Parameter Values from Declare Year, Month, and Day Integer

Tags: parameters, integer, declare

I need to set up an SSRS report with Parameters for Year, Month, and Day.

The following works in SMS (with all my other code), and pulls data for those declared values.

```
Declare
    @Year int = 2017,
    @Month int = 05,
    @Day int = 05;


 Where
    YEAR([Time Stamp]) = @Year
    and MONTH([Time Stamp]) = @Month
    and Day([Time Stamp]) = @Day
```

But, in SSRS I need for end-user to be able to choose whatever Year, Month and Day values they enter and return data. That is NOT working when I change the Declared values to:

```
DECLARE
    @Year int = null,
    @Month int = null,
    @Day int = null;
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Set up a parameter (Name it DATE) as a date with no available or default values.

[image: Parameter Properties]

In your dataset query, change your declare to

```
DECLARE
    @Year int = YEAR(@DATE),
    @Month int = MONTH(@DATE),
    @Day int = DAY(@DATE);
```

SSRS should automatically map the @DATE parameter in the query to your DATE parameter in the Dataset Properties' **Parameters** tab.

[image: Dataset Properties Parameter expression]

Though why not just use the date without the conversions?

```
Where CAST([Time Stamp] AS DATE) = @DATE
```

Comment: Hannover Fist, please see my screen shots. You may have to click on them, as I do not have enough points. Thanks,